# include, require dentro de funções métodos

Tags: php, include, require

Usar [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (ou [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)) dentro de uma função ou método pode ocasionar algum conflito ou problema com versões mais antigas do PHP (como a 5.3)?

Notei que a maioria dos frameworks que trabalha com MVC usa [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) dentro de um método, por exemplo o arquivo `./CodeIgniter/system/core/Loader.php` do CodeIgniter3:

```
public function model($model, $name = '', $db_conn = FALSE)
{
    ...

    foreach ($this->_ci_model_paths as $mod_path)
    {
        if ( ! file_exists($mod_path.'models/'.$path.$model.'.php'))
        {
            continue;
        }

        require_once($mod_path.'models/'.$path.$model.'.php');

        $this->_ci_models[] = $name;
        $CI->$name = new $model();
        return $this;
    }

    show_error('Unable to locate the model you have specified: '.$model);
}
```

Acredito que todos FrameWorks PHP baseados em rotas (e mvc) trabalhem assim, por isto talvez seja algo que não ocasione problemas na versões mais recentes do PHP, mas gostaria de saber referentes a versão 5.3 se pode ocorrer algum problema (não vou usar a versão 5.3 é apenas curiosidade).

Minha preocupação é devido ao [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) geralmente incluir uma classe (vinda do Model ou Controller geralmente) no momento da execução e no comportamento da API (PHP).

Comment: Acredito não haver problemas de compatibilidade, o motivo pelo qual os frameworks utilizam dessa forma é para seguir regras de padrões de projetos como PSR0, PSR1 e etc... [Veja mais aqui](http://br.phptherightway.com/), clique em guia de estilos de códigos.

Comment: Há uns 2 anos, eu estava fazendo um orçamento para um cliente no qual tinha um programador php desses metido a "sabe tudo". Aí o sujeito viu um trecho dos meus códigos e disse que era um lixo. Ele explicou que jamais deve fazer include/require dentro de uma função ou classe. Mas não explicou o motivo e nunca encontrei informação relevante na internet. Acho que ele estava falando bobagem. Ele apenas argumentou que é ruim para performance, que todos os includes e requires tinham que ser feitos em modo procedural, fora de funções ou métodos de classes. Mas nunca encontrei nada a respeito. rsrsr

Comment: @DanielOmine amigo acho que um dia ouvi a mesma coisa (será que foi a mesma pessoa), mas o problema era referente a uma versão antiga do PHP, mas eu procurei em todo CHANGELOG. Começo a achar que isto foi um mito, igual a outros do PHP, que o problema era um (include dentro de uma função trabalha com as variáveis desta função), ou seja só muda o comportamento, alguém entendeu errado e o cérebro destes sujeitos complementaram com mentiras por não saber o motivo real. Eu *acho* que vi uma situação no PHP4, o que pode ser o motivo, este sujeito deve ter pegado informação antiga.

Answer (score 10):

Não existe problema em fazer includes dentro de funções, o que muda é apenas o escopo. Se você faz o include dentro da função, o escopo do include fica apenas dentro dessa função, ou seja, seria como se aquele código incluído fosse digitado dentro da função.

Essa resposta pode ser encontrada no site do PHP na documentação da instrução include: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php.

> Se a inclusão ocorrer dentro de uma função todo o código contido no arquivo incluído irá se comportar como se tivesse sido definido dentro da função. Portanto ele seguirá o escopo de variáveis da função. Uma exceção para essa regra são as constantes mágicas que são interpretadas antes da inclusão ocorrer.

```
// Object.php
<?php
return new Object();
?>

// Classe.php
<?php
class Classe {
    public static function createObject(){
         include_once 'Object.php';
    }
}

// file.php
<?php
$object = Classe::createObject();
var_dump($object instanceof Object); //true
```

Comment: Problemas existem que possam ocasionar um erro na aplicação, sem contar que é uma péssima prática, e o erro citado em questão é quando você está trabalhando com classes.

Answer (score 4):

Não ocasiona problemas. Pelo menos conheço do PHP 5.0 para cima e nunca tive problemas com isso.

`include/require` dentro de funções podem ser feitos normalmente. A diferença é que ela vai ficar "presa" dentro do escopo daquela função.

## Perigos

Uma coisa que talvez você quisesse evitar é que um arquivo que é incluído dentro de uma função ter acesso a funções como `func_get_args` e os próprios argumentos da função.

Examine o seguinte exemplo:

```
  function add_user($user, $id)
  {
       include 'alguma_coisa.php';
  }
```

No arquivo `alguma_coisa.php`

```
$user = null
```

Imagina o que vai acontecer quando ao comportamento da função `add_user`?

Outra problema de dar `include` dentro de um método de uma classe (não confundir com função), é que você tem acesso direto ao `$this`, `self` e `static`, podendo também acessar propriedades privadas e protegidas.

Veja essa pergunta que fiz aqui, onde dou também uma solução para o problema:

[Include dentro da classe e acesso ao $this, self ou static](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76078/include-dentro-da-classe-e-acesso-ao-this-self-ou-static)

## Casos úteis

É claro que não se pode generalizar. Por exemplo, funções de autoload em PHP geralmente utilizam `include` internamente. E isso é amplamente utilizado em framework como `Laravel` e `Codeigniter`. Até mesmo o próprio composer faz uso disso.

Então veja o exemplo de uma implementação com autoload:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class)
{
      return include DIRETORIO_CLASSE . $class . '.php';
});
```

Classes de `View` (a do padrão MVC mesmo) costuma utilizar um `include` para "renderizar" determinado layout feito em PHP.

```
public function render(array $data)
{

    ob_start();
    extract($data);

    include $this->file

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

#FicaADica

Answer (score -3):

A partir da versão 5.0 não há problemas, como comentaram acima, porém é uma péssima prática e você está importando todo um arquivo para dentro de seu trecho de código, e se você estiver trabalhando com classes você terá problemas com instancias.