# Include dentro da classe e acesso ao $this, self ou static

Tags: php, escopo-de-variáveis

Encontrei esse pequeno código dentro da pasta `Composer/ClassLoader.php`, em um projeto onde uso o `composer`.

```
 /**
 * Scope isolated include.
 *
 * Prevents access to $this/self from included files.
 */
function includeFile($file)
{
    include $file;
}
```

O comentário traduzido poderia ser:

> Escopo isolado para `include`. Impede o acesso ao `$this` e `self`

## Testes

Levando em consideração o caso citado acima, percebi que no Laravel 4, eu tenho acesso ao `$this` em qualquer view!

E veja o que acontece no seguinte código numa view qualquer:

```
@extends('layout.default')
<?php
   $this->compiler = 1;
?>
```

É gerado o seguinte erro

> Call to a member function isExpired() on a non-object

E o detalhe interessante é que, como o `include` estaria diretamente no método da classe, eu pude acessar uma propriedade do tipo `protected` e atribuir a ela um valor inesperado para o framework!

Em outros frameworks, como o `Zend`, o `$this` também pode ser acessado na `view`.

## Perguntas

Sendo assim, então me surgiram algumas perguntas:

- Quais seriam outros problemas possíveis causados por um `include` dentro da classe e ter acesso ao `$this` - além dos já citados?
- Numa estrutura MVC, na classe que representa a `view` eu deveria deixar o acesso livre ao `$this`, ou usar uma outra classe para "ser o `$this`" da view, ou outra coisa?
- Quando seria recomendado enclausurar a função `include` e quando não (sempre, nunca ou na maioria dos casos)?

Comment: Se você acha que removi muitas tags fique a vontade para adicioná-las novamente =)

Comment: Acredito que nos próprios códigos em um projeto não há nenhum problema em ter acesso ao `$this` pois, com algumas exceções, não utilizamos a variável `$this` no escopo global... No entanto, para códigos compartilhados entre projetos é sempre importante manter variáveis e métodos que podem quebrar o funcionamento bem protegidos para não sofrer surpresas inesperadas.

Comment: Segue o commit do composer que introduziu essa função: https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/6d7b9afc4b6bd1bc640b4c2b803c7a87f5a59dd9

Comment: O problema que vejo é ter acesso aos métodos `private` e `protected` diretamente.

Comment: Vou continuar sendo insistente. Acho que ainda falta alguma coisa para solucionar essa pergunta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Respondendo à minha segunda pergunta, votaria a favor da alteração do contexto do arquivo incluído, em se tratando da `view` no `MVC`.

E explico:

Quanto ao que diz respeito ao contexto aplicado ao `include` dado dentro de uma classe que representa a uma `view`, já havia elaborada uma solução a pouco tempo atrás - que pode ser melhorada pela comunidade :)

## Problema

- Tenho uma classe, responsável por renderizar a `view`. Porém, quero evitar que os membros dessa classe sejam acessados através do `$this`, mas ao mesmo tempo quero que o template que será renderizado tenha seu "próprio `$this`".

## Solução

- No ato da renderização, utilizar uma `Closure` para enclausurar o template incluído e, ao mesmo tempo, definir um outro objeto como contexto para a `Closure`.

Elaborei isso da seguinte forma:

```php
class View
{
    protected $file;

    protected $data = [];

    public function __construct($file, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return $this->createClosureContext();
    }

    protected function createClosureContext()
    {
        // Cria parâmetros de fachada apenas para obrigar o tipo de argumento

        $caller = function ($file, array $data) {

            unset($file, $data);

            ob_start();

            // Não passa variável, para não colidir com "extract"

            extract(func_get_arg(1));
            
            include_once func_get_arg(0); 

            return ob_get_clean();
        };

        return $caller->bindTo($this->createObjectContext())->__invoke($this->file, $this->data);
    }

    protected function createObjectContext()
    {
        $object = new StdClass;

        $object->Html = (object)'Simulate instance of Helper';

        return $object;
    }
}
```

## Explicação

Como qualquer classe de template [simples], `View` recebe por parâmetro o nome do template e os dados que serão enviados para o template.

O trecho onde a "mágica" em relação ao acesso ao `$this` está aqui:

```php
protected function createClosureContext()
{
    // Cria parâmetros de fachada apenas para obrigar o tipo de argumento

    $caller = function ($file, array $data) {

        unset($file, $data);

        ob_start();

        // Não passa variável, para não colidir com "extract"

        extract(func_get_arg(1));
        
        include func_get_arg(0); 

        return ob_get_clean();
    };

    return $caller->bindTo($this->createObjectContext())->__invoke($this->file, $this->data);
}
```

Criei uma closure chamada de `$caller` e, através do método `bindTo`, defini qual objeto será utilizado como `$this` dentro dessa `Closure`. Essa `Closure` é responsável pela inclusão do arquivo.

O objeto passado em `bindTo` é um simples `stdClass`, que poderia ser qualquer objeto. Nesse caso, defini ele dentro do método `View::createObjectContext()`.

Quando instanciamos, podemos concluir pelos teste que o contexto do `$this` (para o template incluído pela view) foi devidamente alterado.

Exemplo:

```php
new View('tpl.php', ['nome' => 'Wallace']);
```

No template `tpl.php`:

```php
<?php echo $nome ?>
<?php print_r($this) ?>
```

Imprime:

```php
Wallace    
stdClass Object
(
    [Html] => stdClass Object
        (
            [scalar] => Simulate instance of Helper
        )

)
```

Comment: Cara eu estava procurando isto :D foi muito criativo o uso de `func_get_arg`, isto merece +100 :p - Recompensa a caminho!! (Quando leio *até em 7 dias* me lembro da Samara kk)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Samara mano ? hahahahaha

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Do filme o chamado, *Seven daysssss*, sempre lembro da voz dela, as vezes ainda tenho medo de atender o telefone :p

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento clássico a doida que aparece na TV Uhauha

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues hehehe essa mesma, os caras respondem em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured esperando a recompensa de 7 dias devem sentir o mesmo medo, só que no caso de perder a recompensa :)

Comment: Obrigado Senhor @GuilhermeNascimento. Enfim alguém concordando com minhas maluquices no PHP!

Comment: Ontem tentei jogar a recompensa pra ti, mas ainda faltavam 4 horas e hoje eu estava me divertindo no meta :P já esta ae, parabéns, foi muito criativo, mesmo que alguns não entendam!

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade, o Composer usa o autoloader para incluir os arquivos baseados em uma estrutura de diretórios. Por exemplo, a classe `Modules\Db\Adapter`, estaria em um diretório com o arquivo PHP `Modules\Db\Adapter.php`. A função `include` só seria usada explicitamente dentro de um arquivo se o mesmo fosse um código antigo que não comportasse a estrutura de autoloading, onde cada arquivo é uma classe em si.

O acesso a um método/variável por meio de `self` (para variáveis estáticas) e `$this` (para variáveis como objeto da própria classe), só se dá por meio de herança (`extends`) ou se o método/variável pertencer à própria classe.

Os métodos acessados pela view através do `$this`, por exemplo, são métodos que são de visibilidade *public* ou *protected* da mesma classe da `View` ou algum método de mesma visibilidade de uma classe herdada pela mesma.

Comment: Mas temos um problema se uma propriedade da `View`, ainda que `protected`, for uma instância de uma outra coisa (Helper, por exemplo), e "apagarmos" a instância. Isso não seria um problema? Se não fosse, imagino que não teria por que da visibilidade

Comment: O que quer dizer com "apagar" a instância? Para que uma instância seria criada para ser apagada depois?

Comment: Veja meu exemplo que você vai entender. O Laravel temos a propriedade protegida, que é uma instância de `Compiler`. Ao atribuir um valor, causou um erro. É disso que estou falando