# Como fazer um extract dentro de uma função sem que as variáveis colidam com as variáveis de parâmetro?

Tags: php

Tenho  uma função que carrega determinada via com através do `include`. Os parâmetros dessa função são `$file` e `$data`. O parâmetro file é o nome do arquivo que será carregado com `include` dentro da função, e `$data` é um `array` que recebe os valores que serão transformados em variáveis através da função `extract`.

O problema que eu tenho é o seguinte: Se a pessoa passar `array('file' => 'outra coisa')` o valor `file` será transformado em variável, o que colidirá com o nome do argumento que criei chamado `$file`.

Exemplo:

```
function view($file, array $data) {
          ob_start();
          extract($data);
          include $file;
          return ob_get_clean();
   }
```

O problema:

```
view('meu_arquivo.php', ['file' => 'outro valor']);
```

O erro:

> Arquivo 'outro valor' não existe

Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Fiz essa pergunta aqui no SOPT já sabendo a resposta, não me critiquem por isso. Na verdade como não tinha uma pergunta específica sobre o assunto, mas apenas demonstrei através de exemplo, decidi fazer a pergunta, por ser considerado útil  (inclusive o usuário @GuilhermeNascimento me deu 100 pontos de reputação pela resposta que dei a minha própria pergunta).

Comment: O exemplo está aqui, mas a pergunta não trata desse assunto em específico http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76078/include-dentro-da-classe-e-acesso-ao-this-self-ou-static

Answer (score 1):

Você poderá resolver isso utilizando a função quer captura os argumentos passados para uma função, independente do nome da variável.

Essas funções são: `func_get_args` e `func_get_arg`

Veja:

```
function view($file, array $data) {

          unset($file,$data); 

          ob_start();

          extract(func_get_arg(1));

          include func_get_arg(0);

          return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Mas aí vocês podem querer perguntar: "Wallace, por que você deixou as variáveis declaradas como parâmetro na função para depois dar `unset` e usar `func_get_arg`? Isso não é digitação inútil de código?".

Não, pois é proposital, visto que declarando os parâmetros você sempre obriga que o segundo parâmetro `$data` seja um `array`.

Se eu fizesse a função sem os parâmetros (nesse caso em específico), ficaria difícil documentar e entender que a função precisa receber dois argumentos e que o segundo argumento é obrigatóriamente um `array`.