# Como passar variável do controller para view

Tags: php, mvc

Olá, fiz uma aplicação mvc mas estou com problema na hora de passar uma variável do controller para a view. Meu codes:

```
class Home extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $user = $this->loadModel('usersModel');
        $row = $user->getUserData(Session::get('user_id'));

        $this->loadView('_templates/header');
        $this->loadView('home/index');
        $this->loadView('_templates/footer');
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php echo $user; ?>
```

Comment: Transforme `$user` em atributo da classe `Home` e adicione um metodo ` function getUser()` dando um  `return $this->user`;

Comment: Depois, chame o método na view, após instanciar `Home`, com um simples `echo $HomeObj->getUser();`

Comment: poderia fazer isso no meu code? Acabei que não entendi sua lógica

Comment: `loadView()` so faz um include do arquivo?

Comment: @rray sim, um require (tem $data = null nos parâmetros da função)

Comment: passa `$row` no index, `$this->loadView('home/index', $row);`

Comment: Não está claro o suficiente. Isso é algum framework conhecido? Possui documentação? Ou foi vc quem criou o framework? Normalmente deve ter algum compilador para os templates da view. Os helpers da view normalmente devem ter um método de assinatura de variáveis.. é por esse método que passa os dados do controller/model para a view.

Comment: Quem criou o framework foi eu, e não possui uma documentação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabei resolvendo da seguinte forma: transformei o parametro $data em objeto, assim consegui passar o objeto user

```
public function loadView($view, $data = null) {

    if($data) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }

    require APP . 'view/' . $view . '.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `extract` combinados com `func_get_arg()` que fica semelhante a alguns frameworks populares e usar uma função anonima (requer php5.3) para evitar acessar o escopo da classe, como nesta resposta:

- [Include dentro da classe e acesso ao $this, self ou static](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/78253/3635)

Assim evitará o acesso as variáveis `$this`, recomendo também que use a [indução de tipos (Type Hinting)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

```
public function loadView($view, array $data = null)
{
    $load = function ($data)
    {
         if (empty($data) === false) {
              extract(func_get_arg(0));
         }

         require APP . 'view/' . $view . '.php';
    };

    $load($data);
    $load = $data = NULL;
}
```

O acesso no view ficará assim (acredito eu):

```
$row = $user->getUserData(Session::get('user_id'));

$this->loadView('home/index', $row);
```

E no `home/index.php` e o acesso a variável será algo como (sem a necessidade do `$this`):

```
<?php echo $user; ?>
```