# Como escrever variáveis no PHP?

Tags: php, variáveis, estilo-de-codificação

Estava assistindo os vídeos do Robson V.Leite e percebi que em um dado momento ele recupera informações dos formulários para inserir no banco de dados de uma forma diferente da que eu utilizo, única forma até então que eu conhecia. Ele armazena as variáveis em forma de índices. Ex:

```
$f['titulo'] = $_POST['titulo'];
$f['conteudo'] = $_POST['conteudo'];
$f['data'] = $_POST['data'];
```

Porque ele armazenaria as variáveis desta forma e não da forma como eu utilizo desde sempre? Eu faço assim:

```
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$conteudo = $_POST['conteudo'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
```

Comment: Não da para dizer nada nesse contexto. Atribuir um array chave a chave em outro é bem bacana...

Comment: @rray não entendi a sua frase. Porque é **bem bacana**?

Comment: Porque não faz sentido você copiar um array item a item, com qual finalidade? porque não usa o $_POST direto? o que mais é feito com `$f`?

Comment: Onde você pegou essa referência ?

Comment: Se você está criando novas variáveis apenas para armazenar os dados de outra variável, na maioria dos casos seria apenas desperdício de memória. Use a variável original.

Comment: Pelo amor de Deus! não dêem respostas ensinando a usar `extract` diretamente em  `$_POST`, se não vocês criarão um programador que cria códigos inseguros !

Comment: Hoje em dia, até aprender é um risco. Existem ainda muitas outras práticas nada recomendáveis nas respostas.

Answer (score 19):

Você tem que perguntar pra ele. Talvez tentar olhar o contexto.

Eu, por exemplo, não costumo fazer nenhuma das duas coisas (ok, alguns casos eu faço). A maioria faz como no segundo exemplo porque aprendeu fazer assim, a pessoa não se pergunta porque está fazendo isto. Muitas vezes ela acredita que é necessário fazer, sem questionar. Alguns raros casos acreditam que é melhor fazer assim. Pode ser melhor se vai usar a variável vinda externamente múltiplas vezes. Mas a melhoria essencialmente é escrever algo mais simples.

Na verdade eu "não entendo" porque as pessoas adoram criar variáveis onde não são necessárias. Isso ocorre pra todo lado, alguém fez errado ou por um motivo muito específico, aí os outros "programadores" vão copiando sem tentar entender porque se faz aquilo. Deve existir um motivo pra criar variável. Em geral este motivo é que precisa realmente armazenar um valor específico que será usado várias vezes. Eu até entendo que ela pode dar mais legibilidade, mas se vai usar apenas uma vez, não vai fazer nenhuma operação, o `$_POST` está de bom tamanho.

No caso do código dele, também fica mais simples, mas é tão pouco, que eu acho que é melhor nem fazer. Ou faz do segundo jeito ou deixa o padrão.

Claro que o código dele pode estar assim por alguma outra razão que desconhecemos, mas não vou especular sobre isto como em outras respostas, afinal é só especulação.

O fato é que:

1. Não há motivo para fazer isso no contexto apresentado
2. Se especularmos o que ele quer fazer, chegamos a conclusão que a didática dele é ruim por não apresentar os pontos incrementalmente

Se tentarmos adivinhar a intenção não podemos dizer que iria usar como parâmetro do PDO porque a sintaxe é diferente. Se vai ter que mudar a sintaxe depois então porque não deixa para mudar tudo?

E se vai usar em alguma função que espera um *array*, porque não usar o próprio `$_POST`? Pra que criar outro?

Claro que tratar dados externos é importante na maioria dos casos, mas o exemplo não está fazendo isto. E se vai fazer no momento de pegar os dados do `$_POST` é que a verificação/sanitização deve ser feita e aí jogar provavelmente em variáveis locais. Mesmo que jogue em um outro *array* associativo, ainda não está sendo mostrado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: **TL;DR** : "Entenda o contexto, então crie variáveis auxiliares"?

Comment: Acho que não, seria mais um "1. Entenda o contexto. 2. Não crie variáveis auxiliares onde não precisa". Mas pra ter certeza tem que saber o contexto :P

Comment: O contexto é irrelevante nesse caso pois é um curso de introdução ao CRUD  e banco de dados. Eu acho que ele futuramente vai usar isto pra tratar como **array** pra fazer alguma coisa. Variáveis numa boa parte das vezes são irrelevantes, isso é claro

Comment: Contexto sempre é relevante, mesmo que seja um "curso". E justamente por ser um "curso", não deveria ensinar fazer errado. A não ser que o resto do código mostre que tem um motivo para fazer esta operação. Isto é contexto. Se é do jeito que eu estou pensando (só posso adivinhar sem ver o contexto) não deveria usar nada disto, nem a primeira, nem a segunda forma. Se for de outro jeito, a segunda forma não é de toda ruim. Se ele vai usar futuramente, falta contexto e falta didática pra ele. Variáveis não são irrelevantes. Se algum estiver nesta situação, deveria ser removida.

Comment: @bigown Nesse caso acredito que sua resposta induz a deixar no código uma grande falha de segurança. No PHP não tratar as variáveis globais como `$_POST` e `$_GET` é muito arriscado, ainda mais para lidar com banco de dados.

Comment: @marcusagm pelo contrário. Se você tratá-las, estará usando apenas uma vez, e o resultado do tratamento é que será usado dali pra diante. Por isso que eu falo do contexto.

Comment: @bigown o que quero dizer é que existem funções nativas para recuperar esses valores, e abandonar o uso direto dessas variáveis globais.

Comment: @marcusagm primeiro, foi exatamente o que eu falei. Mas se for falar sobre estas funções, é outro assunto. Aqui se pergunta sobre o uso das variáveis. O que vai ser feito com elas é *off-topic* nesta pergunta. Se for olhar pra segurança, as duas formas estão potencialmente erradas. Mas podem não estar, porque querer tratar qualquer coisa sem saber porque está fazendo isto, também está errado.

Answer (score 12):

Em complemento à resposta do @Maniero, realmente é desnecessária a reatribuição de nomes para a variável nesse caso.

A principal consideração é que a variável **vai ter o mesmo valor**.

Na maioria das vezes, as pessoas fazem isso para poder "simplificar" a utilização da variável. Mas isso realmente não se faz necessário.

Do jeito que você demonstrou no exemplo:

```
$f['titulo'] = $_POST['titulo'];
$f['conteudo'] = $_POST['conteudo'];
$f['data'] = $_POST['data'];
```

Seria mais fácil fazer assim:

```
$f = $_POST;
```

Mas isso **não daria vantagem alguma**, pois o valor de titulo, por exemplo, vai continuar o mesmo.

A atribuição das variáveis externas (ou qualquer outro tipo de variável a ser tratada) **seria mais útil se houvesse algum tratamento** em seus valores.

Exemplo:

```
$titulo = trim($_POST['titulo']);

$conteudo = htmlentities(trim($_POST['conteudo']));
```

Perceba, que no caso acima, os valores não serão os mesmos.

Outro caso bastante comum em se utilizar variáveis para "copiar valores" é  em retorno de funções. Pois ao invés de ter que processar tudo de novo, é melhor salvar o valor e reutilizá-lo.

Exemplo:

```
function get_nome_cidade($cidade_id)
{
    // Faz uma consulta na url externa
    // Faz um mapeamento complicado para filtrar os dados

   return $nome_da_cidade;
}
```

Aí poderíamos fazer:

```
 $cidade = get_nome_cidade(10);

 $banco->salva(['cidade' => $cidade]);

 echo "Ele salvou a cidade {$cidade}";
```

Pois assim, já que o valor da função seria sempre o mesmo, mas o custo de sua obtenção sendo alto, poderíamos nos preocupar em salvá-lo numa variável.

Outro fator que eu levaria em consideração é "nomes gigantes".

Pois é melhor fazer isso:

```
 $nome = $_POST['usuario']['nome_completo_usuario']

 echo "O nome do usuário é {$nome}":
```

Do que fazer isso

```
echo "O nome do usuário é {$_POST['usuario']['nome_completo_usuario']}"
```

Mas nesse caso também podemos considerar que usar nomes grandes também é uma prática ruim - talvez você vai esquecer dos nomes, de tão grandes que são!

E, pra complementar, não existe nada de errado entre seu jeito de fazer e o jeito dele. Só é desnecessário, na minha opinão.

Answer (score 10):

Apesar de várias respostas boas aqui já existentes, vou colocar dois motivos aqui que talvez sejam bem fortes para o uso disto.

Mas antes devo lhe dizer que isto não é um índice e sim associativo, o índice usa números:

```
$f['titulo'] = $_POST['titulo'];
$f['conteudo'] = $_POST['conteudo'];
$f['data'] = $_POST['data'];
```

Os prováveis motivos são:

- **Usar funções nativas do php**

  Se você usar arrays associativas, poderá usar várias funções do PHP pra tratar estes dados, por exemplo:

  - `array_​change_​key_​case`, `array_​chunk`, `array_​column`, `array_​combine`, `array_​count_​values`, `array_​diff_​assoc`, `array_​diff_​key`, `array_​diff_​uassoc`, `array_​diff_​ukey`, `array_​diff`, `array_​fill_​keys`, `array_​fill`, `array_​filter`, `array_​flip`, `array_​intersect_​assoc`, `array_​intersect_​key`, `array_​intersect_​uassoc`, `array_​intersect_​ukey`, `array_​intersect`, `array_​key_​exists`, `array_​keys`, `array_​map`, `array_​merge_​recursive`, `array_​merge`, `array_​multisort`, `array_​pad`, `array_​pop`, `array_​product`, `array_​push`, `array_​rand`, `array_​reduce`, `array_​replace_​recursive`, `array_​replace`, `array_​reverse`, `array_​search`, `array_​shift`, `array_​slice`, `array_​splice`, `array_​sum`, `array_​udiff_​assoc`, `array_​udiff_​uassoc`, `array_​udiff`, `array_​uintersect_​assoc`, `array_​uintersect_​uassoc`, `array_​uintersect`, `array_​unique`, `array_​unshift`, `array_​values`, `array_​walk_​recursive`, `array_​walk`, `arsort`, `asort`, `compact`, `count`, `current`, `extract`, `in_​array`, `key_​exists`, `key`, `krsort`, `ksort`, `list`, `natcasesort`, `natsort`, `next`, `pos`, `prev`, `range`, `reset`, `rsort`, `shuffle`, `sizeof`, `sort`, `uasort`, `uksort` e `usort`

  Um bom exemplo é o `array_map`, com ele é possivel acessar todas variaveis fazer algo com elas, por exemplo procurar todos valores que sejam possivelmente palavras e aplicar `ucwords` (é um exemplo básico apenas):

  ```
  function ucwords_array($n) {
      if (preg_match('#[a-z]#i', $n) > 0) {
          return $n;
      }
      return ucwords(strtolower($n));
  }

  $f = array_map('ucwords_array', $f);
  ```

  Após isto você pode extrair os dados de `$f` usando `extract()`:

  ```
  $f['titulo'] = $_POST['titulo'];

  $f = array_map('ucwords_array', $f);
  extract($f);

  echo $titulo;
  ```
- **Usar views em frameworks:**

  Um exemplo de framework que usa as arrays associativas é o Laravel, mas quando acessa no *view* as variáveis estão extraídas, provavelmente usando o `extract()`, aqui um exemplo de rota:

  ```
  Route::get('/', 'UserController@home');
  ```

  UserController.php:

  ```
  class UserController extends Controller
  {
      public function home(Request $request)
      {
          $f = array();

          $f['titulo']   = $request->input('titulo');
          $f['conteudo'] = $request->input('conteudo');
          $f['data']     = $request->input('data');

          return view('greeting', $f);
      }
  }
  ```

  View:

  ```
  <html>
      <body>
          <h1>Titulo: <?php echo $name; ?></h1>
          <p>conteudo: <?php echo $conteudo; ?></p>
          <p>data: <?php echo $data; ?></p>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

### Concluindo

Nem sempre isto será útil e na maioria poderá até mesmo ser totalmente redundante. Sobre o vídeo, eu não entendo muito o motivo dele fazer isto, talvez porque ele goste assim, ou porque ele esteja tão acostumado ou só tenha aprendido desta maneira.

Não vou criticar pois não sei qual vídeo você esta falando eu até procurei, mas não achei. Mas vou dizer uma coisa que vale para qualquer programador, até pra que já tem experiencia, existem muitas maneiras de ser fazer uma mesma coisa, até o começo deste ano eu fazia algumas coisas nos meus códigos de uma maneira, mas ao longo do ano mudei totalmente os meus hábitos. Isto é normal, as vezes pensamos ser a maneira mais pratica ou correta, mas ao longo do tempo encontramos novos maneiras (e até manias).

Uma coisa vou lhe dizer, não acredite em tudo que lhe falam, ou siga exatamente como lhe disseram, eu já ouvi muita coisa errada que soaram como corretas, veja esta duvida:

- [include, require dentro de funções métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60314/3635)

Eu achei até erro na documentação php:

- [O parâmetro use_include_path foi substituído pelo parâmetro flags?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66277/3635)

Isto é para qualquer linguagem, não só php.

Comment: Que legal hein !!!! Gostei dessa resposta. No sentido de se guardar as variáveis dentro do **$f** que é o array possibilitando este array ser trabalhado por todas as funções acima citadas e inclusive extraídos em forma de índices, variáveis ...

Comment: @MarcosVinicius editei e coloquei um exemplo do Laravel, fico feliz que a resposta lhe pareça útil :) Obrigado!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, No Laravel geralmente você não usa a varíavel $_POST, e sim o método `Input::get`. Imagino que você deve ter feito isso com exemplo. Outra coisa é que, se é necessário passar os dados para view, não é necessário reatribuir a variável. Basta passar ela diretamente `view('minha_view', $_POST)`. O que muita gente confunde é que `$_POST`, apesar de ser uma superglobal, é um array comum, podendo se remover com `unset` como qualquer outra variável (e pra mim não deveria ser tratada de maneira especial, a ponto de ter que reatribuir).

Comment: No exemplo do `array_map`, você não precisa reatribuir o valor também! Você poderia criar diretamente `$f = array_map('funcao', $_POST)`. A não ser que você queira trabalhar com alguns dados de `$_POST` e outros não. Nesse caso, no `laravel` você pode usar `$f = Input::only('texto', 'conteudo', 'data')`.  Já no PHP puro, você teria que reatribuir. Ou seja, se o AP estiver pegando alguns dados do `$_POST`, e não todos, isso é útil. Se não, isso é inútil.

Comment: Na verdade eu não estava explicando sobre o `$_POST`, era algo mais voltado ao vetor, talvez eu tenha usado como exemplo o código do autor em um lugar que pode confundir. @WallaceMaxters mas realmente a sua dica é totalmente valida +1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim estou ciente sobre o laravel e como funcionam as camadas, no entanto como disse talvez o exemplo não foi dos melhores, meu foco realmente era explicar o quando se fará necessário usar usar uma array. Talvez depois eu edite.

Comment: Não estou dizendo que a resposta foi ruim, @GuilhermeNascimento, foi só um comentário ;)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu sei :P e por isto positivei, entenda que toda critica construtiva é positiva e foi o que você fez, eu apenas concordei contigo dizendo que realmente não escolhi o melhor exemplo.

Answer (score 6):

Sem o contexto fica difícil de explicar o motivo dele armazenar as variáveis em um único array. Talvez já esteja preparando para passar as variáveis como parâmetros para a execução do PDO, como o exemplo abaixo:

```
$params = array();
$params[':id'] = $_POST['id'];
$params[':name'] = $_POST['name'];

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = ":id" AND name = ":name"';
$res = $conn->prepare($sql);
$res->execute($params);
$list = $res->fetchAll();
```

Porem receber váriaveis via `$_POST` e `$_GET` diretamente é um risco, pois essa variáveis podem ser manipuladas pelo usuário, deixando brechas para SQL Injection por exemplo.

Para recuperar valores das variáveis globais sempre utilize as [funções de tratamento](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php). Utilizar as variáveis globais diretamente [é uma prática não recomendada](http://br.phptherightway.com/#filtro_de_dados).

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Apesar do PDO já tratar os valores para impossibilitar SQL Injection quando usado como no exemplo que dei é muito importante que valide os valores recebido nessas variáveis, assim não correrá o risco de deixar falhas desconhecidas.

Sobre a forma como cada um cria as suas variáveis, alguns dizem que melhoram a legibilidade, outros julgam como besteira, outros veem como ocupar memória atoa, mas o que importa é ter consciência sobre o que está fazendo.

Comment: Apesar da resposta não estar focando no que foi perguntando, concordo com isto. O problema é que o *link* indicado fala para fazer algo sempre, como se fosse um regra única. E ela não é tão verdade assim. Como você disse tem que saber o que está fazendo. Seguir regra porque alguém disse é que não pode. Mas nem quero continuar nestes assunto, porque além de ser *off-topic*, vai provocar debate.

Comment: Não está fora do contexto, na verdade tentei mostrar um exemplo de aplicação para o primeiro caso e não julgar o que ele fez. Como a pergunta não contextualiza fica difícil definir, a parte do tratamento e segurança é um bônus, e concordo com você alguns casos usar essas funções não é conveniente, porem não é a maioria dos casos. Só para concluir o assunto.

Comment: Não precisa das aspas duplas: `'SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = :id AND name = :name';`

Answer (score 5):

Tecnicamente e conteitualmente, em ambas as formas, não há problema.

O que pode definir se uma técnica, estilo ou mesmo um conceito é mais adequado que outro é o objetivo final.

Os dados serão usados com qual finalidade?

A partir desse ponto decide-se qual técnica utilizar.

A técnica usando um array para receber o array `$_GET` ou `$POST` tem a vantagem de poder ser mais simples de gerenciar. Como exemplo, se precisar excluir tudo, basta excluir um único objeto.

```
$f['titulo'] = $_POST['titulo'];
$f['conteudo'] = $_POST['conteudo'];
$f['data'] = $_POST['data'];

/**
Aqui faz os paranauê..
*/

/**
Após terminar tudo que tinha para fazer, podemos descartar simplesmente assim:
*/
 unset($f);


/**
No outro modo teria que fazer isso:
*/
unset($titulo);
unset($conteudo); 
unset($data); 

/**
Uma forma resumida
*/
unset($titulo, $conteudo, $data);
```

*Isso é um mero exemplo. Obviamente se fosse só essa a vantagem, seria ridículo.

Afinal, qual o melhor?

Não existe, nesse caso, qual o melhor. Sempre que pensar "qual o melhor", pense sempre que existem N formas de resolver algo chegando a um mesmo resultado. Ao invés de pensar "qual o melhor", pense "qual o mais adequado para esse modelo de negócio?".

Para qualquer técnica, pense onde deseja chegar. Qual o objetivo. Qual o resultado que espera obter.

Pense também na performance. O que custa mais para ser executado? 
Vale a pena usar um recurso mais sofisticado que consome mais processos para algo pequeno e simples? Vale a pena escolher um caminho simples por ser mais fácil mesmo que tenha que modificá-lo futuramente para uma implementação ou criar algo robusto e modular para simplificar implementações futuras?

As escolhas dependem do planejamento, o qual é baseado no modelo de negócios.

**Vamos ver na prática, uma situação mais sofisticada.**

Por quê não usar diretamente as variáveis globais `$_POST` e `$_GET`? Por quê consumir memória "clonando" os mesmos dados?

Em sistemas mais sofisticados, podemos querer manter o dado original recebido por `$_GET` e `$_POST`, pois no momento do recebimento, precisamos fazer validações, sanitizações e filtragens.

Uma sanitização ou uma filtragem pode modificar os dados originais recebidos. Para um modelo de negócios que deseja enxergar os dados originais, não é bom negócio. Por isso, nesse caso é mais adequado "clonar" os dados para um novo objeto onde os dados serão manipulados e, os dados originais permanecerão intactos.

**Elimine redundâncias**

Uma dica simples que evita repetição de códigos.

Ao invés de receber um a um

```
$f['foo'] = $_POST['foo'];
$f['bar'] = $_POST['bar'];
```

Apenas receba o array inteiro

```
$f = $_POST;
```

Caso queira criar variáveis com os nomes dos índices, utilize *variáveis variáveis* num laço de repetição

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v)
    $$k = $v;
```

Comment: Daniel, esse último exemplo do `foreach` é totalmente inseguro. Você pode possibilitar ao  cliente alterar a variável do seu sistema, já que você está definindo as variáveis dinamicamente. Pense: Se eu tenho uma variável chamada `$usuario` e o cara maliciosamente criar um formulário (via console ou mais avançadamente com postman) ele poderá alterar o conteúdo de sua variável. Foi por isso que `register_globals` foi removida do PHP, por conta dessa insegurança

Comment: sim Wallace. Foi meramente um exemplo, pois, antes de permitir criar variáveis variáveis dessa forma, deve-se ter um controle dos nomes dos parâmetros permitidos para tal. Se formos discutir todos os detalhes e suas ramificações, tornaria a resposta muito complicada e ampla. Para tais detalhes básicos, espera-se que o programador esteja ciente, haja em vista que o foco aqui não é especificamente sobre segurança

Comment: Também não precisa ter procupação em ensinar tudo tão a fundo. Um programador iniciante, inexperiente, não consegue assimilar tudo o que um experiente ensina, principalmente se for algo muito extenso e complexo. Pense nisso como se estivesse conversando com uma criança ou um bebê. Quando uma criança pergunta sobre o que é um computador, por exemplo, você não vai dar uma aula sobre a historia dos computadores, eletrônica, lógica de programação, engenharia, etc.. Você vai dizer que é um tipo de TV para abrir youtube e assistir pepa pig.. Sacou?

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Marcos,

O que ele está fazendo é armazenar os valores obtidos por post em um array, cujos valores recebem uma chave string que os identifica, ao invés de uma chave numérica do tipo integer 1, 2, 3 e etc.

Se isso é melhor ou pior, depende unicamente do que você quer fazer com esses valores depois. Se vai precisar iterar sobre esse array com um laço por exemplo.

Answer (score -2):

Você só não soube separar o joio do trigo.

Isso não é uma variável, isso é um array `$f`, com uma chave "titulo":

```
$f['titulo'] = 'título';
```

Isso é uma variável:

```
$titulo = 'título';
```

Variáveis foram inventadas para armazenar um determinado valor e carregá-lo através de métodos, condições, etc...

Já o array é utilizado para mapear uma coleção, ou carregar uma quantidade superior de dados.

Você pode utilizar ambos, isso vai depender da sua necessidade, a diferença é que utilizando na forma de array, você terá uma elasticidade maior, porém irá armazenar mais memória para isso.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php