# Mover variáveis para fora de um vetor em PHP

Tags: php

Eu tenho um controller que irá passar informações de exibição para uma view, essas informações serão objetos, e eles serão passados em array.

```
namespace app\controllers\conteudo;

class index
{
    public function get_index()
    {
        // Supondo que eu já tenha os objetos $usuario e $publicacao instanciados e populados.

        $args = array
        (
            $usuario,
            $publicacao
        );

        $view = new \app\views\view();
        $view->pagina('publicacao', $args);
    }
}
```

E uma função que irá carregar uma página do template e exibir essas informações.

```
namespace app\views;

class view
{
    private $template;

    public function pagina($arquivo, $args = null)
    {
        require(getcwd() . "/app/views/templates/{$this->template}/{$arquivo}.php");
    }

}
```

No arquivo do meu template, eu consigo acessar `$args[0]` e `$args[1]`, porém não gostaria de ter acesso à essas variáveis dessa forma, e sim como `$usuario` e `$publicacoes`.

Eu poderia definir variáveis para pegar esses valores, porém o problema é que os parâmetros que serão passados são incertos, então se eu passar `$categoria` por um array, eu quero ter acesso à `$categoria` no arquivo do template.

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Um `extract()` em `$args` é uma opção os indices vão virar variáveis. Deve ter outras maneiras de resolver isso.

Comment: É uma pergunta parecida: [include, require dentro de funções métodos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60314/91)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma opção para isso é usar [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) para transformar os indices em variáveis

```
$arg_vars = ['categoria' => 'sapatos', 'descricao' => 'sapato de couro', 'valor' => 200];
extract($arg_vars);
echo $descricao;
```

Ou no seu projeto:

```
public function pagina($arquivo, $args = null)
{
    if(!empty($args)){
       extract($args);
    }
    require(getcwd() . "/app/views/templates/{$this->template}/{$arquivo}.php");
}
```